# Swagger is not working in integration with ZendFramework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, swagger

Could you please suggest why Swagger is not working for me in integration with ZendFramework2. I followed the instructions given [here](http://www.davenewson.com/tutorials/php/rest-api-documentation-in-zend-framework-2-with-swagger).

**composer.json**:

```php
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.5",
        "outeredge/swagger-module": "dev-master"
    },
}
```

**config/application.config.php**:

```php
<?php
    return array(
        'modules' => array(
            'MyApp',
            'SwaggerModule',
        ),
        'module_listener_options' => array(
            'module_paths' => array(
                './module',
                './vendor',
            ),
        ),
    );
?>
```

**/config/autoload/swagger.global.php**:

```php
return array(
    'swagger' => array(
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../../module/Morpho/src/Morpho/Controller',
        ),
        'resource_options' => array(
            'output' => 'array',
            'json_pretty_print' => true, // for outputtype 'json'
            'defaultBasePath' => null,
            'defaultApiVersion' => null,
            'defaultSwaggerVersion' => '1.2',
        ),
    )
);
```

After I deploy the application under Apache, when call http://myapp/public/api/docs, I get:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"An error occurred during execution;
please try again later.","error":"error-exception","exception":
"class":"Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException",
"file":"\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php",
"line":930,
"message":"An exception was raised while creating "Swagger\Swagger";
no instance returned"
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
 0 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(1057): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'swaggerswagger', 'Swagger\Swagger')
 1 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(633): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('swaggerswagger', 'Swagger\Swagger')
 2 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(593): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Swagger\Swagger', 'swaggerswagger')
 3 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(525): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
 4 \vendor\outeredge\swagger-module\src\SwaggerModule\Controller\DocumentationController.php(39): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Swagger\Swagger')
 5 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): SwaggerModule\Controller\DocumentationController->displayAction()
 6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
 7 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
 8 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
 9 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
 10 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(113): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
 11 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
 12 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
 13 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
 14 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
 15 \public\index.php(10): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
 16 {main}"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`swagger-module` seems not active. Please try https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php instead.

Answer (score 0):

### I was getting same type of error and able to fix the issue by following.

**1)** Create **swagger.local.php** file in **\config\autoload**
 **(**in Development system  swagger.development.php**)**

**2)** **swagger.local.php** have following content.

```
return array(
    'swagger' => array(
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../../module/Api/src/Api/Controller',
        ),
        'resource_options' => array(
            'output' => 'array',
            'json_pretty_print' => true, 
            'defaultBasePath' => '/',
            'defaultApiVersion' => null,
            'defaultSwaggerVersion' => '1.2',
        ),
    )
);
```

Thanks

http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in